# Using a C library in a C++ application with Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, compiler-errors, linker

I'd like to use this gamepad library (https://github.com/elanthis/gamepad/) written in C in my C++ application. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

So far I've tried to create a shared library and link it using Qt's GUI. When trying to run my C++ program I still get the error **"main.cpp:89: Error: undefined reference to `_imp__GamepadInit'"** which seems to tell me that the library wasn't properly linked yet.

My main application looks like this:

```
#include "gamepad.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GamepadInit();
    return 0;
}
```

As I'm pretty clueless my question is: what would be the basic steps to use functions of this library (given the .c & .h files) when working with Qt Creator/MinGW?

Comment: use `extern C ...`

Comment: From what I see the header of the library has `extern C` defined in line 12 (https://github.com/elanthis/gamepad/blob/master/gamepad.h#L12). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to link it.

Comment: That exactly is what I need to now, like how can I link it? Do I really need to create a DLL file from the given source files or is there any other way to just include them? Even with a .dll/.a I got the same error after including the library using the Qt GUI dialog to add an existing library.

Comment: It looks like yes, you need to build that project to get dll (and also .lib) files, because it is distributed only in source, I can't see pre-built binaries there

Comment: @mvidelgauz Alright, I had to build the library with Visual Studio. Now it works. Thanks!